# Events on sharepoint Home screen

Tags: sharepoint-online

Good afternoon, 
we have created a sharepoint Intranet site, on which we share information to our employees.
One of the parts is an Event Webpart in which we would like to display the upcoming Birthdays for the coming 2 weeks.

The forward filter is working perfectly and only showing the next 2 weeks.
Our problem is that it is also displaying older birthdays from 2-3 months ago  (see screenshot, Today is 16-05 so it sould only show the one from 23 & 28 may which are marked in yellow) ...

Are we doing something wrong ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the filter look like? Can you provide a screenshot of what your filter is currently set to?

Comment: The filter is as follows :
Source -> This site
Category -> Birthdays
Date Range -> Next 2 weeks

I have also added a screenshot (note it is in dutch)

Answer (score -1):

[Check This link add filter to show only future events](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-the-events-web-part-5fe4da93-5fa9-4695-b1ee-b0ae4c981909)

Edit Webpart->In the webpart pane you see source select the required filter. it works for me

Comment: Unfortunately for us it's not.
For example if we select only show the next 2 weeks it indeed shows the upcoming  only for the next 2 weeks forward, unfortunately at the same time the older events also remain visible, even events which are dated 1-2-3 months back ...